# Chef - Trying to add an apache2 alias to a vhost file

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm new to Chef and am running an AWS OpsWorks environment and deploying code via Chef 11.10. I am trying to create two `alias` lines within the vhost file on an instance running apache2:

```
alias /foo /my/dir/name/
alias /bar /another/my/dir/name
```

I have a custom cookbook in an S3 bucket that OpsWorks is successfully pulling and distributing to all instances. Within that custom cookbook, I have a recipe called `vhosts.rb`:

```
include_recipe "apache2"

web_app "Test1" do
  server_name "Web1.com"
  server_aliases ["www.Web1.com"]
  allow_override "all"
  docroot "/srv/www/web_test/current/sites/"
end
```

This creates a vhost file just fine, but I cannot figure out how to add the alias lines. I've looked through the OpsCode default apache2 cookbook, and I cannot find any reference to generic `alias` commands/params in `default.rb`, `mod_alias`, `web_app`, or `web_app.conf.erb`.

How can I add these alias lines? I'm sure this is easy, but I'm drowning trying to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apache2 cookbook's `web_app` provider doesn't support adding `Alias` directives in the generated conf file.  The simplest way to accomplish what you're going for would be to extend the template file at `templates/default/web_app.conf.erb` and add a block similar to the following:

```
<% if @aliases -%>
   <% @aliases.each do |alias| -%>
     Alias <%= alias %>
   <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Then, change your `web_app` call to be:

```
web_app "Test1" do
  server_name "Web1.com"
  server_aliases ["www.Web1.com"]
  allow_override "all"
  docroot "/srv/www/web_test/current/sites/"
  aliases ["/foo /bar", "/baz /meh"]
end
```

The `web_app` definition will pass through any extra params to the template, making them available as instance variables.

Note: there are techniques of varying complexity for modifying the template file.  You can simply change it in your S3 files directly or you can do a full blown wrapper cookbook and manage that via Berkshelf.